# Flowbite CSS plugin is not working when including it in tailwind.config.js

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Flowbite (both JS and CSS) in my application. JS was inserted and works (using Webpack and `import 'flowbite'` in the entry point JS).

For the CSS, I'm using this in the `tailwind.config.js` file as the documentation tells you to do.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ]
}
```

However when compiling everything (`npx tailwind build`) the CSS doesn't seem to be included in the final CSS file.

I can tell because the FlowBite modal should have a dark background (making everything except the modal darker), but that background does not appear when creating the compiled CSS.

When I do include the flowbite.css manually though, it does render correctly. So the current working solution I have is (in my HTML):

```
<!-- TODO: Adding the plugin in tailwind.config.js does not work -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@latest/dist/flowbite.min.css" />
```

But I'd like to have it compiled automatically from the Tailwind build command.

Comment: Can you share how you included the JS file? Interactive components are not working in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in the Discord community answered to me directly. I had to include this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.html', './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'],
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ]
}
```

The `'./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'` in `content` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

In doc: `<script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>` 
So we need to change to correct path to our flowbite dist in node_modules. Example: `<script src="./node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -6):

Tried many way doesn't work.
So I have quick fix, add this css:

```
.h-modal{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```